# Using Rust dereferencing operators &* vs * with Self?

Tags: rust

I want to write an LRU Cache with a memory size limitation rather than the "number of objects" limitation in std.  After trying to figure it out for myself, I cheated and looked at [an existing implementation](https://github.com/thestinger/rust-core/blob/master/core/lru.rs), and I *almost* understand it, but this stops me:

```
struct KeyRef<K> {
    k: *const K,
}

impl<K: Hash> Hash for LruKeyRef<K> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        unsafe { (*self.k).hash(state) }
    }
}

impl<K: PartialEq> PartialEq for LruKeyRef<K> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &LruKeyRef<K>) -> bool {
        unsafe { (*self.k).eq(&*other.k) }
    }
}
```

It's that last `unsafe` line that I don't understand.  I'm using a `HashMap` as the underlying structure, the key is stored with the value, and I want the hasher to be able to find it. I make the working hash key a reference to the real key and provide `Hash` and `PartialEq` functions such that the `HashMap` can find and use the key for bucketing purposes.  That's easy.

I understand then that I have to compare the two for `PartialEq`, and so it makes sense to me that I have to use `*self.k` to dereference the current object, so why `&*other.k` for the *other* object?  That's what I don't understand.  Why isn't it just `*other.k`?  Aren't I just dereferencing both so I can compare the actual keys?

Comment: The `&` is there because [`PartialEq#eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq) takes a reference; `*other.k` would be moving the key, and `other.k` would be passing the pointer. Anything else unclear on this matter? Some side notes: Where have you found that implementation? That use of pointers is not something you should see everywhere.

Comment: Okay, then why does it work for `*self.k`?  I don't get the assymmetry here.  It wouldn't be assymetrical in, say, C++.

I found the example from an old libcore proposal: https://github.com/thestinger/rust-core/blob/master/core/lru.rs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We wish to call `PartialEq::eq`:

```
trait PartialEq<Rhs = Self>
where
    Rhs: ?Sized,
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool;
}
```

Assuming the default implementation where `Rhs` = `Self` and `Self` = `K`, we need to end up with two `&K` types

1. `other.k` is of type `*const K`
2. `*other.k` is of type `K`
3. `&*other.k` is of type `&K`

This much should hopefully make sense.

1. `self.k` is of type `*const K`
2. `*self.k` is of type `K`

The piece that's missing that that [method calls are allowed to *automatically reference* the value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#wheres-the---operator) they are called on. This is why there's no distinct syntax for a reference and a value, as there would be in C or C++ (`foo.bar()` vs `foo->bar()`).

Thus, the `K` is automatically referenced to get `&K`, fulfilling the signature.

Comment: Ah, that was the missing piece.  What an odd consequence of that protocol. And damned confounding to see it in the wild like that, but now that you've documented it, I better understand it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
impl<K: PartialEq> PartialEq for LruKeyRef<K> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &LruKeyRef<K>) -> bool {
        unsafe { (*self.k).eq(&*other.k) }
    }
}
```

Under typical circumstances, we can call methods taking `&self` with just a reference to the object. In addition, a chain of references to the object is also implicitly coerced. That is, we can write:

```
let a: &str = "I'm a static string";
assert_eq!(str.len(), 19);
assert_eq!((&&&&str).len(), 19);
```

In your case however, we start with a pointer, which must be explicitly dereferenced inside an unsafe scope. Here are the types of all relevant expressions:

```
self.k : *const K
(*self.k) : K
other.k : *const K
&*other.k : &K
```

Since [`equals`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html#tymethod.eq) takes a reference on its right-hand member, we must make it a reference. Unlike in C++, you can not just pass an lvalue as a reference without making this reference-passing explicit, nor can you pass an rvalue to a const reference. You can however, prepend `&` to a literal in order to obtain a reference to it (`foo(&5)`). It only appears asymmetrical because (in a way) `self.k` is the caller and `other.k` is the callee.