# How is the expression &*T possible in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a BST implementation and inorder traversal code:

```
pub struct Node {
    data: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

fn inorder(root_node: &Box<Node>) {
    if let Some(left) = root_node.left.as_ref() {
        inorder(&*left);
    }
    print!("{:?} ", root_node.data);
    if let Some(right) = root_node.right.as_ref() {
        inorder(&*right);
    }
}
```

This function works, but I'm confused about how the line `inorder(&*left)` is possible. Given that the function takes `&Box<Node>`, that means that `*left` is a `Box<Node>`. Doesn't `*` downcast a box, i.e. where `left = Box<T>, *left = T`. If so, how is `inorder(&*left)` correct?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Using Rust dereferencing operators &* vs * with Self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43218554/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: More usefully, can you explain why it **wouldn't** be possible?

Comment: In your code `left` is already a `&Box<Node>`, so `&*` is a noop, which you can [remove](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4c1f8c3e467ae2258621d9aa4de0432) without breaking anything…

Comment: @Jmb thank you for your comment. I probably confused myself, copying previously written code